# htaccess rewrite caps to lowercase

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help in redirecting all caps (or Camel case or any case) category link to lower case category link.

For Example:

```
hostname/category/Case (should be redirected to) - hostname/category/case
hostname/category/CASE (should be redirected to) - hostname/category/case
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the internal `RewriteMap` function `tolower`, as detailed in the [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int) documentation:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [R]
```

Note that I've not tried the above, I just looked at the mod_rewrite docs.  Looking at the rule, you may need to put `[N]` in there in order to re-run the rule for CamelCase:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [N]
```

However, you could also check if the server has [mod_speling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html), which is the preferred option if you want your URI's to be case-insensitive.